# суммирование данных в datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable

Здравствуйте, имеется таблица подобного вида.
[image: Начальная таблица]

Если столбцы position, description и characteristic совпадают, то происходит суммирование значений Quantity. То есть в результате должна получиться таблица [image: Конечная таблица]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
select Position, Description, Characteristic, sum(Quantity) as Quantity
from SomeWhere
group by Position, Description, Characteristic
```

Comment: Извините за подобную тупость, пытаюсь разобраться - не получается.

Comment: @Вячеслав, это sql.

Comment: Спасибо, это я понял. С sql и linq не сталкивался раньше никогда. Если Вас не затруднит, вы не могли бы объяснить, как написать это на linq.

Answer (score 2):

Linq запрос. Вместо SomeObj используйте свой класс.

```
SomeObjCollection.GroupBy(o => new {o.Position, o.Desctiption, o.Characteristic})
            .Select(gr =>
            {
                return new SomeObj
                {
                    Position = gr.Key.Position,
                    Desctiption = gr.Key.Desctiption,
                    Characteristic = gr.Key.Characteristic,
                    Quantity = gr.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                };

            });
```